# Navigate through Scene Delegate

Tags: ios, swift, storyboard, uiscenedelegate

I'm trying to get the blue screen view of my storyboard, but  I'm entirely new to this. I don't understand how to navigate through the classes to get to "the blue screen," and it gives me errors.

[Story Board Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5Kwg.png)

The original idea is to propagate the variable "managedObjectContext"(CoreData) through this function in the SceneDelegate.

The error I get is: Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[UIViewController]'

[This is my SceneDelegate Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ewvU.png)

```
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
    // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
    // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
    //guard let _ = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
    
    let mainViewController = window!.rootViewController as! UINavigationController
    
    if let navViewControllers = mainViewController.viewControllers { //error Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[UIViewController]'
        let  controller = navViewControllers.first as! EditViewController
        controller.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext
    }
    
    
    listenForFatalCoreDataNotifications()
    
    return
}
```

Comment: The error is just telling you that `if let` is meaningless here. Get rid of it.

Answer (score 0):

I have decided to propagate the object "managedObjectContext" through the segue. In this case, it has worked better for me because I did not understand very well how to navigate through the storyboard in the scene app

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    switch segue.identifier! {
    case addSegueIdentifier:
        guard let navController = segue.destination as? UINavigationController,
        let saveVC = navController.topViewController as? EditViewController else {
            return
        }
        saveVC.managedObjectContext = managedObjectContext
    default:
            break
        }
}
```